# Make CSS: "resize: horizontal" work with Mat-Table on firefox

Tags: html, css, angular, resizable, mat-table

I have a mat-table and wanted to make the columns resizeable, so I stumbled across the CSS property "resize" which works perfectly well for regular HTML tables

Basic HTML:

```
 <table id="main_table">
          <tr class="header">
            <td><div class="tableHeaderCellDiv">Tech Name</div></td>
            <td><div class="tableHeaderCellDiv">Name</div></td>
           </tr>
   </table>
```

CSS:

```
.tableHeaderCellDiv { resize: horizontal;  overflow:hidden;}
```

Which gives the headers a very nice box with which you can resize the columns.
However, when trying to bring this exactly same thing over to my mat-table, the drag-box simply didn't show up.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="items" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" *ngFor="let column of displayedColumnsMAT">
    <th mat-header-cell class="custom-mat-header-styling tableHeaderCellDiv" *matHeaderCellDef>{{column}}</th>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row class="tableHeaderCellDiv" *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsMAT; sticky: true;" ></tr><!-- for the header row -->
</table>
```

I've cut out the not-header-rows for both examples, as they don't matter for now.
I've also tried inserting tableHeaderCellDiv (same CSS as for the plain HTML) as a class everywhere, guessing that that is the problem.

What am I doing wrong, or could it be that that feature simply does not work at all with Mat-Tables?

**[EDIT:]** thanks to @KrishnaRathore I now know that my code (probably) isn't the problem but Firefox is. If you're content with Chrome check out his answer though, it works.

**HOWEVER**, this problem seems to be unique to Mat-Table, as there is another small plain HTML table in my project with which the resizing works fine.

Comment: Hi check bellow link. [link](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11377)

Comment: I know that thread, but it's a feature request for a pure-angular option, still thanks though

Answer (score 1):

use this code

**[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/make-css-resize-horizontal-work-with-mat-table?file=app/table-basic-example.html)**

**component.scss / component.css**

```
.tableHeaderCellDiv { 
    resize: horizontal;  
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

**component.html**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns">
        <th mat-header-cell class="custom-mat-header-styling tableHeaderCellDiv" *matHeaderCellDef>{{column}}</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element[column]}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row class="tableHeaderCellDiv" *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true;"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't help me much though, because the problem is just flat out Firefox (and IE). Your example didn't work until I switched to Chrome, which is sadly not an option for my project.
Still thank's a lot, because I now know that the CSS resize won't do it at all

Comment: 2nd comment: my other answer works with firefox as well. 
I have absolutely no clue why or how, but your answer gave me the idea to try something else, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have made it work (even on firefox), but I am absolutely certain that I tried this before and then it just didn't.

```
<th mat-header-cell class="custom-mat-header-styling" *matHeaderCellDef><div class="tableHeaderCellDiv">{{column}} </div></th>
```

so the trick is to have another div INSIDE the header cell, which is resizeable, and to not make the rest resizeable.